# Background-attachment:fixed откуда высчитывает начало?

Tags: css

От начала экрана или начала элемента?

Comment: Но так не происходит!!! (((

Comment: от левого верхнего края окна браузера....

Comment: @Air точно - сорри

Comment: А если возможность сделать что бы от конкретного элемента он высчитвал

Answer (score 3):

от левого верхнего края окна браузера...

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 90vw;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40vh;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  background-image: url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1636783/96989b87-2116-4678-a8ee-ae113469504d/s1200?webp=false);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 205px 205px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```